# Website javascript doesn't work unless I'm using LiveServer on VSCode to load it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Navbar toggle isn't working?

Javascript:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

HTML

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">
          <h1>LIST CONVERT</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="#">SQL List</a></li>
                <li><a href="add-zeroes-or-characters-to-list.html">Expand Item Size</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I am using liveserver on VSCode the navbar menu created by this works perfectly, however when I simply open the file from my finder into the browser, the navbar no longer works?

Here is the CSS in case that's necessary:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  color: var(--white);
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--darkblue);
  align-items: center;
}

.brand-title {
  margin: 0.5em;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: var(--primaryblue);
}

.navbar-links .selected {
  background-color: var(--primaryblue);
}

.navbar-links .selected-light {
  background-color: var(--lightblue);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
.navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links .selected-light {
    background-color: var(--darkblue);
  }
}
```

I'm just now getting into implementing CSS and JavaScript into HTML, sorry if the code isn't the best! Still got a lot of work to do!

Comment: `when I simply open the file from my finder into the browser` when you do this, you aren't using a HTTP server - so, a LOT of functionality simply won't work - you need a HTTP server (software) to host a web site

Comment: Sweet! Sorry I don't know much about HTTP and servers, I'll start doing some research on that. If I update my website into a host like namecheap. Will the javascript work correctly then?

Comment: not "http and servers" ... http server ... like, apache, nginx, IIS, caddy - of course, there's much simpler ones two that could work - and yes, it will work - since it works using liveserver - which is simply a "http server"

Comment: Lol I understand, my learning path for all this is supposed to get into actually hosting websites and all that I believe it should teach me that stuff next. Thank you so much! If you can put your comment as an answer to the entire thread I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jaromanda X said, some things dont work when opening a file without using an HTTP server. If you press F12 on your web browser to open developer tools, and check on the console you may see some errors there.

If you are using chrome, you can install an extension like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) which creates a local web server to test that kind of stuff. There are a lot of other options as well, like the VSCode one.

Comment: I'll accept the answer in a few mins stackoverflow says I have to wait 5 mins